# Setting margin and padding to zero in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Here is a staged site i'm working on can you tell me how to properly set margin and padding to 0 so that in IE there are no gaps in hte header.

http://stage.momentosentierrasanta.org/

I'm getting a small space, and it's driving me crazy.

Here is a screen shot of IE7 and IE8 in top screen shot and then IE9 lower screen shot:

[image]

Comment: Seeing no gaps in Firefox or IE7, can you include a screen shot?

Comment: What version of IE you are using? in 8 and 9 I don't see any gaps...

Comment: I'm testing in IE7... and in IE8. Let me include a screen shot

Comment: Not seeing any gap in IE8 here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that is the IE8 behavior, I tested many sites and seen that it can be removed in IE. I tried to add for div#ifcjNav{margin-top:-20px;} but is dragging up div without to remove that line and If I add a css reset even then wont remove top line. Try to add on top a background transition color to mask that line.
Good luck.